# PHP foreach: Multiple conditional search in array decode from JSON

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have some problem in making a function by 'foreach' to return the result I want.
My example array of data decode from JSON:

```
$json_string = 
'{"010_INICHK": [
        {
          "Symbol1": "01",
          "Symbol2": "",
          "Desc": "000_Start"
        },
        {
          "Symbol1": "",
          "Symbol2": "0701",
          "Desc": "010_Exchange"
        },
        {
          "Symbol1": "87",
          "Symbol2": "",
          "Desc": "025_MEASURE}
],
"020_PROCESS1": [
        {
          "Symbol1": "69",
          "Symbol2": "",
              "Desc": "000_REDO CLN"
        },
        {
          "Symbol1": "",
          "Symbol2": "6341",
          "Desc": "115_AFT CLN"
        }
        ],
"030_PROCESS2": [
        {
          "Symbol1": "75",
          "Symbol2": "",
          "Desc": "010_MT Load"
        },
        {
          "Symbol1": "",
          "Symbol2": "6341",
          "Desc": "020_AFT Load CLN"
        }
    ]
}'
```

My search logic:

```
 1. use "lookup_main" to search 010_INICHK, 020_PROCESS1 or 030_PROCESS2, if found go to step 2. else return "UNDefine".
 2. Then use "lookup_sub"(4 digits) to search "Symbol2" in 010_INICHK, 020_PROCESS1 or 030_PROCESS2 (depends on result in step 1.) if not find, use "lookup_sub"(first 2 digits) search "Symbol1".
 3. If found, return array ['lookup_main', "Desc" value] else return "UNDefine"
```

**For example**,

I want to use ['030_PROCESS2', '6341'] to find and return ['030_PROCESS2', "020_AFT Load CLN"].

My code like this:

```
function vlookup($lookup_main, $lookup_sub, $lookup_array, $lookup_column, $result_column){

if ($lookup_main == $look_array[0]){
    foreach($lookup_array as $item_array){
        foreach($item_array as $item){

            if ($item[$lookup_column] == $lookup_sub) {
                return $item[$result_column];
            }elseif($item[$lookup_column] == substr($lookup_sub,0,2){
                return $item[$result_column];
            }else{
                echo 'UNDefine'; //undefine step
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'UNDefine';
}
return false;
}

$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
$result = array($lookup_main, vlookup('030_UBM1', '6341', $data, 'Symbol2','Desc'));
echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

But the output is [null 115_AFT CLN]...
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it and have some way to search faster? (PHP 7.0)

Comment: Well, first at all, did you define `$lookup_main` previously in your code ? Because at the moment you never define it. As far as I understand, you want to return the `$lookup_main` too. So you could `return [$lookup_main, $item[$result_column]];` instead of hardcoding it in your `$result` variable. And if you don't find the `$lookup_sub` then just `return [$lookup_main, false];`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your suggestion, I will read it and fix it :)

Comment: @Frankich it's helpful me, thanks :) do you have any other idea about my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` with `json_decode`

```
$jArr   = json_decode($json_string, true);
$search =  ['030_PROCESS2', '6341'];
$r = [];
array_walk($jArr, function($v, $k) use ($search, &$r){
  ($search[0] == $k) ? ($r[0] = $k AND array_walk($v, function($v1, $k1) use ($search, &$r){
    ($search[1] == $v1['Symbol2']) ? ($r[1] = $v1['Desc']) : ($r[0] = 'UNDefine');
})) : ($r[0] = 'UNDefine');
});
echo implode(',',$r);
```

[Working DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ZYJif)

Comment: Thanks for your short and clean reply, it's solved part of my problem! but the efficiency of `array_walk` is better than `foreach` in PHP 7.3.1?